# recount to fix primary id in mysql

Tags: mysql

after inserting 5 row of table with primary KEY and remove middle of data how to recount to fix primary counts? for example i have this row

```
|id |name

| 0 |mahdi
| 1 |mojtaba
| 2 |maryam
```

after remove mojtaba from row i have this:

```
|id |name

| 0 |mahdi
| 2 |maryam
```

how to recount id to fix this table:

```
|id |name

| 0 |mahdi
| 1 |maryam
```

Comment: why you want to do that? if u have this PK as FK is some other table then it would be problem...

Comment: You could try [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)

Comment: @bobthyasian, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` does not change values in the rows. That would be very bad if it did!

Answer (score 0):

I would say this will not be ***FIX*** for primary key, it would be ***MESS*** for a primary key.

If you have this primary key as foreign key for some other tables, then handling those while updating something like above would be very tedious work.